# How to expand $1/(e^{a-b} +1) - 1/(e^{a+b} +1)$ for $a\gg b$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've tried Taylor expansion, but could get nowhere.
Could anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this. My first thought is: Since $a\gg b$, we have $a-b\approx a$ and $a+b\approx a$, and hence the expression $1/(e^{a-b} +1) - 1/(e^{a+b} +1)$ is approximately $0$.

Comment: Well, I'm really looking for an algebraic expression,  so I can tell how close to 0 it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some hints**

I think we can collect the denominators like this:

$$\frac{1}{e^{a-b}(1 + e^{-(a-b)})} - \frac{1}{e^{a+b}(1 - e^{-(a+b)})}$$

Since $a >> b$ we can use the Geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{(1 + e^{-(a-b)})} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-(a-b)k})$$

$$\frac{1}{(1 - e^{-(a+b)})} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-(a+b)k})$$

We can approximate to the very first two terms each one:

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-(a-b)k}) \approx 1 - e^{-(a-b)}$$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-(a+b)k})\approx 1 - e^{-(a+b)}$$

Thence we substitute those into the terms we got before:

$$\frac{1}{e^{a-b}}(1 - e^{-(a-b)}) - \frac{1}{e^{a+b}}(1 - e^{-(a+b)})$$

Arranging the terms:

$$\frac{1}{e^{a-b}} - e^{-a + b - a + b} - \frac{1}{e^{a+b}} + e^{-a-b-a-b}$$

So using $\exp$ properties to arrange a bit more:

$$e^{-a+b} - e^{-2(a-b)} - e^{-a-b} + e^{-2(a+b)}$$

This is already a good step, but you may try to improve it or have fun somehow!

Comment: Starting to feel you`re one of the trouble shooters around.